# How to calculate average number from points within a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, data, field-calculator, point

I have multiple data points that represent the center of a survey plot with a radius of 5, 10, or 15 feet.  These points also contain percent coverage of different plants.

These points are within different polygons.

Using area of the survey site, I would like to average percentage of this coverage, and then using that estimate the total coverage of each plant across the polygon.

Which tools would I use to calculate this?  I have attempted to use the field calculator but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to [intersect](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) your survey plots and area polygons. The result should be a set of polygons with the survey plots cut up and identified by radius area.

[image]

Create a new field in that table to hold the percentage of total area. And if there isn't one, you need a new area field for the new, cut up shapes.

Use Field calculator to create a new field to divide the total area of the survey plots.